# Como faço para saber que um arquivo foi lido completamente em Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Esse é meu código:

```
Arquivo = open("arquivo.txt", "r")

for linha in Arquivo.readlines():

    if linha == "123":
        print("123")

    else:
        print("Não é 123")

        # Nesse if que não sei como fazer isso
        if linha == "":
            print("Arquivo lido com sucesso!")
```

Comment: Coloque após o for uma print, se o for terminar significa que leu todas a linhas.

Comment: Como já dito, basta colocar um `print` **depois** do `for` (fora dele, não dentro como vc fez). Se terminou o loop é porque leu tudo. Aproveitando, `readlines` é desnecessário nesse caso, pois ele lê o arquivo e cria uma lista com todas as linhas, então na prática vc passa por todas as linhas duas vezes: uma pra criar a lista e outra para fazer o `for`. Mas como vc só quer ler uma a uma e depois descartá-las, não precisa criar essa lista, basta fazer `for linha in Arquivo`

Answer (score 1):

Para o seu caso, bem  simples, somente um `print` após o loop seria suficiente, porém se for inserido um `break` posteriormente a mensagem seria ainda exibida mesmo quando o laço foi encerrado antes de finalizar o arquivo.

Nesse caso, você pode utilizar o `else` do laço, que é executado apenas quando todas as iterações são executadas sem interrupção:

```py
with open('arquivo.txt') as stream:
  for line in stream:
    print(line)
  else:
    print('Arquivo lido com sucesso')
```

Outra forma é validar se ainda existe conteúdo no arquivo para ser lido:

```py
import os

size = os.path.getsize('arquivo.txt')
with open('arquivo.txt') as stream:
  ...
  if stream.tell() == size:
    print('Arquivo lido com sucesso')
```